# Incident & Accident Investigation

Tags: accidents, accident-investigation, incidents

Does the airports have there own incident/accident investigation depts? or they are restricted to the NCAA/Safety dept only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incident & Accident Investigations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74266/incident-accident-investigations)

Comment: That question was closed @tsg

Comment: @GdD this is an exact duplicate by he same author.

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail @QuentinH!

Comment: @Hakimi, if your question was closed before because it lacked detail you aren't going to have any more success posting an identical one. Please add more detail to this can be answered, if you don't know what details to add feel free to ask in comments or chat.